# Wordpress not showing 404 for wrong category names

Tags: wordpress

I have set the permalinks for the posts to /%category%/%postname%/.

But the issue is, for the URL where the post name is right but the category name is wrong, it still shows the post instead of showing 404.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you flushed the permalink settings by re-saving the permalinks?

Comment: Yes, I did. Issue is website.com/category/post works, but website.com/asdf/post also works. Which i want to stop.

Comment: Are these categories for your generic posts or for a custom post type?

Comment: They are generic posts.